# How to evaluate directly Associated Laguerre Polynomial multiplied with $e^{-x/2} x^{k/2}$?

Tags: special-functions, laguerre-polynomials

The Associated Laguerre Polynomial orthonormality relation reads:

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} dx f^k_n(x) f^k_m(x) = \delta_{n,m}
\end{align}
Where,
$$
f^k_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}} e^{-x/2} x^{k/2} L_n^k(x) 
$$

Is there a way to directly calculating $f^k_n(x)$ without evaluating $L_n^k(x)$ first?

Comment: Could you detail your question ? Do you want to check the orthonormality relation ? Do you want to compute a given value like $f_1^1(1)$ ?

Comment: @Abezhiko I want to compute $f_n^m(x)$ for large integers $n,m > 100$ for any x. The Associated Laguerre Polynomial is not a bounded function and in numerics with floating point arithmetic for when $ L_n^m(x) \gtrsim 10^{308}$ it results in `inf` in a C++ program. On the other hand as $f_n^m(x)$ is normalized, it is a bounded function so for large $n,m$ it should not result in ill defined `inf`, `nan` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may take advantage of their generating function. Indeed, the Laguerre polynomials are gathered together as the "coefficients" of the series
$$
F_x(t) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty L_n^k(x)t^n = \frac{e^{-xt/(1-t)}}{(1-t)^{k+1}},
$$
which can be then recovered thanks a contour integral, namely
$$
L_n^k(x) = \oint_{C_r} \frac{F_x(t)}{t^{n+1}} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{2\pi i},
$$
where $C_r$ is a circle centered at the origin with radius $r < 1$, hence
$$
f_n^k(x) = \sqrt{\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}}\, x^{k/2}e^{-k/2} \oint_{C_r} \frac{F_x(t)}{t^{n+1}} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{2\pi i},
$$
which you can evaluate thanks to the residue theorem.